# Windows batch variable in for-loop

Tags: batch-file

I created a quick batch file to check on valheim server and do backup of the save as it's not in the server folder, but i want to make it easier with variables.

would like to set a variable here
`for %%a in (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\LocalLow\IronGate\Valheim\worlds\Dedicated.db)`

eg `for %%a in (%%valserverdb\Dedicated.db)`

How can this can be done?

```
@echo off
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq valheim_server.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "valheim_server.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Valheim Server is running
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" echo Valheim Server is not running starting it. | E:\gameservers\valheim\start_headless_server.bat

SET valserverdb=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\LocalLow\IronGate\Valheim\worlds
SET valbackup=E:\gameservers\backup\IronGate\Valheim\worlds

for %%a in (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\LocalLow\IronGate\Valheim\worlds\Dedicated.db) do set valserverdbcheck=%%~ta

for %%b in (E:\gameservers\backup\IronGate\Valheim\worlds\Dedicated.db) do set valbackupcheck=%%~tb

if "%valserverdbcheck%" gtr "%valbackupcheck%" (xcopy "%valserverdb%" "%valbackup%" /S /E /Y) else (@echo File has not been changed. skipping)

timeout /t 300 /nobreak > NUL
goto loop
```

Comment: just by reading `File has not been changed`, the [archive-attribute comes to my mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36952026/2152082)

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" echo Valheim Server is not running starting it. | E:\gameservers\valheim\start_headless_server.bat
```

This runs `E:\game...rver.bat` and provides `Valheim Server is not running starting it.` as input on `stdin` to that `.bat`.

I'd suggest you replace `|` with `&` to execute both the `echo` and run the `.bat`.

--

Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.

`if "%valserverdbcheck%" gtr "%valbackupcheck%"` compares the two dates a strings, not as date-values. I use `dd/mm/yy...` format for date, so for me, if the server date was `01/02/2021` (Feb 1st) and the backup date was `31/01/2021` then since "01/02/2021" is less than "31/01/2021" the comparison would not choose the appropriate option. I'd suggest `neq` would be a more appropriate comparison-operator.

`%%a in (%%valserverdb\Dedicated.db)` is incorrect syntax. Please provide examples of the what the prior and desired strings are.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input, after some thinking i wouldn't be able to do a 15 min check on the files, i would have to  convert it to UTC and do a check there, i don't know how to do that. so ill just skip it for now. i will just do backup of the files when the loop repeats.

I have changed | to &

Thanks for the help :)